# How to match multiple columns and find specific column value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dataframe in Pandas. It stored in df that works similar to this:

```
 +--------+--------+-------+
 |  Col1  |  Col2  | Col3 |
 +--------+--------+-------+
 | Team 1 | High   | Pizza |
 | Team 2 | Medium | Sauce |
 | Team 2 | Low    | Crust |
 +--------+--------+-------+
```

I need `Col3` value, which have `Col1=Team 2` and `Col2=Medium`.

I tried below code for this:

```
result = df.loc[(df[Col1 ]=='Team 2) ' AND (df[Col2 ]=='Medium'), 'Col3'].values[0]
print(result)
```

Expected result:

```
'Sauce'
```

But I getting error. Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&` for bitwise `AND` - solution working if always data matched:

```
result = df.loc[(df['Col1'] =='Team2') & (df['Col2']=='Medium'), 'Col3'].values[0]
```

Another solution with `next` and `iter` for return default value, if no match data:

```
s = df.loc[(df['Col1'] =='Team2') & (df['Col2']=='Medium'), 'Col3']
result = next(iter(s, 'no matching')
```